# How do you connect events in view controllers created entirely in code, no Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I have created a UINavigationController with a UINavigationBar that has a UIBarButtonItem in the right position ENTIRELY in code, there is no IB/.xib file.

As a newcomer to XCode (v4) from C# I am trying to understand how to trap and handle the click event of the button in the navigation bar.

In C# there would be a click event that you would override which would contain the event handling code.

I have found a number of samples that use the IB to connect UI objects such as a button to a method in the view controller. However, I can not find any examples of how to achieve that solely in code.

Any references of insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your viewDidLoad method create the UIBarButtonItem using one of the following initialisers...

```
– initWithImage:style:target:action:
– initWithTitle:style:target:action:
```

The last two parameters to the initialisers allow you to specify the object to invoke when the action occurs and the method on that object to call i.e.

```
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(methodForItem:)];
```

[Apple's UIBarButtonItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Target/Action on the right bar button item. So after you instantiate your `UIBarButtonItem` you'll do something like this.

`[barButtonItem addTarget:self action:@selector(methodThatShouldBeCalled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, what you propose here will work for a UIButton, not a UIBarButtonItem.